# Submit a form in a jQuery Dialog box and close upon successful POST to MVC Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, form-submit, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using the method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152817/jquery-modal-window-to-display-a-table-in-mvc) to create a pop-up to show a form where the user must "sign" it and then click submit. I have the pop-up working and displaying data. Now I want to submit the form to a POST action and close the pop-up if the POST was successful.

I have been scouring the internet looking for something close to what I think I am looking for, but seeing anything. Can someone offer me some direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do it manually via http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ (it has on success callback) or use jQuery ajax form plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form